# Dynamic ExpiringMap

Tags: java

I am using `ExpiringMap` to get the long waiting object expired. In this API timeout time is predefined and cannot be changed based on object put into queue.

Is there a similar `Java API` to make me set `timeout` time for each object?

**ExpireMap Source Code:**

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ExpiringMap.htm

Comment: Where did you get this class `ExpiringMap` from? It's not a standard JDK class.

Comment: added a link into the question

Comment: There is an implementation of an expiring map with these characteristics: https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap

Comment: @fge thanks, Map<String, String> map = ExpiringMap.builder()
  .variableExpiration()
  .build();

map.put("foo", "bar", ExpirationPolicy.ACCESSED, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Which Map object is used, I could not find 4 parameter passing put mmethod of map object.